# Load a div from a wordpress site (php) into a ASP.net site

Tags: jquery, asp.net, ajax

Situation: I have an ASP.NET website on witch I'm trying to load via ajax .load() method a div containing a mega slider generated on a Wordpress site. (So I could have a slider with an administration interface embedded in my ASP.net website. The wordpress site is hosted intro a virtual directory ("slider") on my ASP website, so cross domain is not an issue. The problem is that the load result is blank. If I'm loading any other div, containing text, it works.

```
$(function(){
$(".slider").load("slider/?page_id=84 #slider-wrapper");});
```

So, basically, I have a target ASP.net site with an empty div and a host Wordpress php site that has a slider in a div generated by a plugin.

Can this be done?

Comment: Ignore my last comment.  Does the slider require a javascript include or css to work?  You'll obviously need to include them in your aspx page as well.

Comment: It works with a plugin, so I assume it needs both JavaScript and CSS to work... And PHP I guess...

Comment: No - the php will run on the server and render the html you see in the page, so your load call is fine.  Just make sure you include the relevant js and css in the page you're doing this on and it should work (in principle).  Is it a publicly accessible page?  I'd happily take a look for you.

Comment: @Archer the website is http://alko-garden.ro/. I'm trying to load the div from http://alko-garden.ro/slider/?page_id=84 Note that the later is an alias (virtual directory) for http://sliders.in-stock.ro/?page_id=84 . I have included all css and js files in my master page. If I make the call `$("#slider").load("/slider/?page_id=84");` it loads the page, slider included. But if I try to load just the slider div from the page (`$("#slider").load("/slider/?page_id=84 #rev_slider_1_1_wrapper");`, it loads nothing.

Comment: I see a lot of scripts in the page that holds the slider, that aren't in the page you want to hold the slider in.  You need to include all the scripts and css that are required for the slider, or it will never work.